# How JMX objects are mapped into SNMP OIDs?

Tags: spring, monitoring, jmx, snmp, apache-camel

I have a standalone Java application written with Apache Camel which I want to monitor via SNMP. I think Camel uses Spring's JMX (@ManagedAttribute, @ManagedResource etc) and I can see various Camel-related objects in JDK jconsole just fine. When I run my app with SNMP enabled:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.snmp.interface=127.0.0.1
-Dcom.sun.management.snmp.port=16101 
-Dcom.sun.management.snmp.acl=false
```

I can connect with SNMP browser to it and I can see lots of stuff there as well. So far so good, but in order for me to make use of it I need to know or figure out how JMX objects are being mapped into SNMP OIDs. Is there are way to find out how it's being done or at least by whom - Spring, JVM? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if the information I found on Google (BTW... first hit eh! ;) ) is still relevant nor do I have the means to poke around and verify (corporate, locked down workstation... sigh!) but, it looks like the default SNMP implementation is not very extensible.

According to ["JVM Monitoring: JMX or SNMP?"](http://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/jmx_vs_snmp) you can only access what is defined in the [JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB.mib](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB.mib)

I'd be interested if the matter has changed meanwhile...

Comment: Good find. Thanks. I looked at that post but somehow that phrase didn't jump on me. From the tests I have done it's certainly looks that only standard JVM JMX properties are being exposed via SNMP. Too bad :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just expose your annotated Spring-managed beans via SNMP. The command line parameters you listed were simply for monitoring metrics regarding the JVM itself, see [SNMP Monitoring and Management](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/snmp.html); hence there's probably no way to *figure out* the OIDs but you have to define them yourself, presumably with another mature SNMP framework or library.

Answer (score 0):

Camel uses the javax.management.MBeanServer to register mbeans. I dont recall we do anything in relation to SNMP. I assume JMX would provide integration for that out of the box, as the JVM has a SNMPAgent that ought to bridge to JMX.

Comment: Well, I think it does provide integration but my question is how do I figure out OIDs (SNMP identifiers) from JMX ids? :)

Comment: btw I wasn't trying to answer this. Just wishing you could comment, and have it as the same "level of visibility" as an answer. Because when people add comments, those are ease to miss.

Comment: Fair enough :) Thanks for commenting.